# Yii2: orderby in find()->where() method

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to make a query to the database to retrieve a list of favorite products by category

In the category there is an attribute called sortcode
after that I have a $categoryids : [3242,1231,6343,1232]
and products

```
$products = Product::find()->where(['category'=>$categoryids])->all();
```

But the result was not as I expected, item in `$products` sort by index
Now I want all product in category 3242 should be ranked first, then to 1231 ...
How do I get the results I want?
Sorry for my bad English!
Thanks in advance and have a nice day !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use where in condition

```
$products = Product::find()
     ->where(['in','category',$categoryids])
     ->orderBy('category DESC')
     ->all();
```

or if you want to sort it by category's shortcode you should join with categorys table, not tested yet but should works :

```
$products = Product::find()
    ->where(['in','category',$categoryids])
    ->joinWith(['categorys' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('shortcode');
    }])
    ->all();
```

don't dorget to add categorys relations in your Product's model.

```
public function getCategorys()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer [Yii2 orderBy()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#orderBy()-detail)

```
$products = Product::find()
            ->where(['category'=>$categoryids])
            ->orderBy(['here_your_category_id' => SORT_ASC])
            ->all();
```

Comment: I don't use orderby because category_id has has order not like sortcode field

Comment: i dont know what you excectly get ? please give detail info.

Comment: also add table info.